# Convergence of $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}}$

Tags: distributions, expected-value, convergence

For a random variable $X$ on $[0, 1]$ with $F(1) = 1$ and $F(x) < 1$ for all $x < 1$, show that $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} \to 1$ as  $r → ∞$. If $F$ is such that $F(x) < 1$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and all moments exist, then show $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} \to \infty$ as  $r → ∞$.

Can someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 1):

The limit $\lim_{r \to \infty} (E[|X|^r])^{1/r}$ equals to somehting called $L_{\infty}$ norm of random variable $X$ that is defined as $||X||_{\infty} = \sup\ \{x \in \mathbb{R}: P(|X|>x) > 0 \}$. Then if $X \in [0, 1]$ and $F(1) = 1$ it is clear that $P(|X|>1) = 0$ but for any $\epsilon> 0$ $P(|X|>1-\epsilon)>0$ so $||X||_{\infty} = 1$. Similarly, if $F(x)<1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $P(|X|>r) > 0$, hence $||X||_{\infty} = \infty$.

It is left to show that $\lim_{r \to \infty} (E[|X|^r])^{1/r} = ||X||_{\infty}$. For this, you first have to show that $(E[|X|^r])^{1/r}$ is nondecreasing in $r \in (0, \infty)$ (Hint: use the Jensen;s inequality) then that would mean that $\lim_{r \to \infty} (E[|X|^r])^{1/r} = \underset{r < \infty}{\sup}\ (E[|X|^r])^{1/r}$. Then you should show that $\underset{r < \infty}{\sup}\ (E[|X|^r])^{1/r} \le ||X||_{\infty}$, and separately that $||X||_{\infty} \le \underset{r < \infty}{\sup}\ (E[|X|^r])^{1/r}$. See [this](http://mesokurtosis.com/posts/2015-04-28-lp-norm-limits.html) and [this](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall18/sta711/lec/wk-05.pdf) for further hints. Hope this helps.